# Why Jacobson, but not the left (right) maximals individually?

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, ring-theory, representation-theory, quiver

When we are working with Path Algebras, it does not need very sophisticated tools to prove that for a finite, connected, acyclic quiver $Q$, the Jacobson Radical of $KQ$ is nothing but the arrow ideal.

But, I have never seen or found any description of the left or right maximal ideals of the path algebra for a given quiver, even under the assumptions we had above (finite, connected and acyclic). Expect for some simple examples, which repeatedly appear in texts, or talks and lectures, I am inclined that textbooks and notes intentionally skip this classification, may be due to complexity.

It is quite puzzling to me why neither in textbooks, nor in presentations, this question is even addressed! 
"We know that in the aforementioned setting, intersection of a certain class of ideals of $KQ$ is the arrow ideal. Would not it be nice to know how the elements of this class look like individually? i.e, could one classify all the maximal (right) ideals of such a path algebra, or in a bit more general setting?"

Any reference which might address this question would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The description of the maximal left ideals is more or less equivalent to the description of the simple left modules, and *that* you will find in every textbook.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez, Thanks for your comment. But, I was wondering if you could elaborate on your answer a little bit.
Classification of simple modules of every given finite quiver doesn't seem complicated. But, can you describe the maximal left ideals of any given finite quiver in an explicit way?
If that is the case, then why do we restrict ourselves to the acyclic case?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez, I wish to clarify that I understand the connection between the left maximal ideals and left simple modules you alluded to in your comment. One side is straight forward, when you have a left maximal ideal. But, explicit description of the other side is not crystal clear to me.